# Antivirus for a mail server to scan emails for virus

Tags: email, anti-virus, exim, email-server

I have a requirement as follows
"I have a site in which the end user is asked to upload a file which is directly sent to the client. Those files are not stored on my server. Now the issue is I don't want my client to complain having virus in the files which go through my mailing server to his systems. So I want to scan all the email traffic in order to detect and remove the virus in the email docs posted by the users."

Is there any way I can do this??
Is there any kind of antivirus which can sit along with email server and scan the email traffic??

Open to any kind of suggestions..

Comment: What kind of email server are we talking about?

Comment: Pretty much any major "Enterprise" or "Business" grade anti-virus solution has some sort of mail server (usually Exchange) integration.  Need details on platform (OS/mail server).

Comment: What platform (unix, windows, AS/400, VAX/VMS, CP/M, ...)?

Comment: And why not scan the mails after upload before mailing them? Creating a MIME mail (encode) and then scanning (decode) is a bit stupid, isn't it?

Comment: I'm using EXIM.. its my mail server.

Comment: I'm using CPanel WHM to check the configuration and all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Exim, I would recommand looking into Mailscanner (http://mailscanner.info) with SpamAssassin.  I used this for years and it's incredibly effective and flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is something for it. For example [amavisd-new](http://www.amavis.org/) is a good start for it and can integrate multiple (all?) virus scanners for Linux.

The documentation tells you how to integrate into Exim. And the installed version gives you information in the README how to integrate the virus scanner(s).

Answer (score 0):

There's [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) and it [integrates well](http://wiki.exim.org/ClamAV) with Exim.